# Unable to install signed apk file in any mobile other than Nougat phones

Tags: android, apk

1. I generated a signed apk file & trying to install on a mobile device.
   But the app is not installing. Its showing app is not installed popup.
2. I'm able to install the apk in mobile with Nougat & the app is fully functional in debug mode.
3. Can anyone give me possible reason & solution for this issue.

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'realm-android'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 25
       buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "prasenjit.com.pickcel"
           minSdkVersion 20
           targetSdkVersion 25
           versionCode 5
           versionName "1.5"
           multiDexEnabled = true
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       }
       sourceSets {
           main {
               assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
           }
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       productFlavors {
       }
   }

   repositories {
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
           maven { // this is for realm-db
           url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
       core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
       compile project(path: ':material-login')
       compile project(':MPChartLib')
       compile project(':materiallettericon')
       compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart-Realm:v2.0.2@aar'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
       compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
       compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4`enter code here`.2'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

Comment: Uninstall the previous version of your app, if any.

Comment: post the gradle...

Comment: You might have some requirements in manifest, for example if you need GPS and a device you are trying to install on does not support it. This is just an example, better post app.gradle file and Manifest.xml

Comment: post defaultConfig of gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution for my issue. 
Its something called Environment change in mobile OS which happens when we try to install signed apk & unsigned apk multiple types.
Once installed from play store, i tried to reinstall the above signed apk & its working.

Comment: It's a very basic problem. You should always be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone settings, find you app inside installed apps list and do uninstall for all users

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer